# Attempting more generic c code, custom data structure, in double linked list, this possible?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm attempting to refactor some code, to reduce duplication.

This is a curated example, currently defined in each .c file.

```
struct hrentry_t
{
    int custom1;
    int custom2;
    int custom3;

    struct hrentry_t *prev, *next;
};

struct hrentry_t*
attachentry(struct hrentry_t* hentry)
{
    struct hrentry_t* hnew = calloc(sizeof(struct hrentry_t), 1);
    if (hnew == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if (hentry != NULL) {
        while (hentry->next != NULL) {
            hentry = hentry->next;
        };
        hentry->next = hnew;
        hnew->prev = hentry;
    }
    return hnew;
}
```

https://github.com/techzilla/check_snmp_extras, is the entire codebase.

I'm declaring and initializing a custom double linked list, and corresponding allocate function. If I moved the linked list functions and code to the common lib .c and .h, how can I get the file specific data inside of each list entry?  Each file requires different types and number of variables.

Maybe I make a the double linked list contain only prev next and data?  Then somehow make data a handle to an incomplete struct?  How would then that need to be allocated though?  I'm open to fully reconsidering my approach, so solid advice from experienced coders is always appreciated.

Comment: External links go bad over time. Please include your code in your question.

Comment: K, grabbed some example sections.

Comment: @TechZilla do not reinvent the wheel. [Read about how Linux does linked lists](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/)! (hint - they're not like this)

Comment: I just noticed that *that doc* (not the current linux kernel) has got some fishy code for finding the offset of a member - for which one uses the standard `offsetof` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to make your specialized list data types castable to a generic double-linked list structure.  This can be accomplished by putting the non-specialized data members at the beginning of the structure:

```
struct node_t {
    struct node_t * prev, * next;
};

struct hrentry_t
{
    struct node_t node;

    int custom1;
    int custom2;
    int custom3;
};
```

It then makes sense to cast an `hentry_t*` to a `node_t*`.  The signature of your attachment function becomes:

```
struct node_t* attachentry(struct node_t* node);
```

And to use it, you cast instances of your specialized type to the generic type:

```
struct hentry_t * my_hentry_ptr;  /* initialized somehow... */
my_list = attachentry((struct node_t*)my_hentry_ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are returning hnew if there is already a linked list present rather than the previous list with hnew added onto the tail of it.

```
return hrentry;
```

try this